# DevExpress AspxGridView clientside SelectionChanged problem when using paged ObjectDataSource

Tags: events, devexpress, client-side, aspxgridview

The context is as follows: 
One DexExpress AspxGridView with a server-side paging/filtering/sorting mechanism (using ObjectDataSource).

I've been having problems with the filter mechanism ( see this [stack](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2455349/devexpress-aspxgridview-filter-in-objectdatasource) ).

Now, the problem I'm having is this: the client-side events get mangled between DataSource events. :O . 
Let me explain what happens: if I change the page (or sort/filter for that matter), then, select one row from the grid, the client-side SelectionChanged event fires well. If I change the page (or sort/filter), the event doesn't fire anymore. Instead, on the server side, I get a "The method or operation is not implemented" exception with the following stack-trace:

```
    at DevExpress.Web.Data.WebDataProviderBase.GetListSouceRowValue(Int32 listSourceRowIndex, String fieldName)
   at DevExpress.Web.Data.WebDataProxy.GetListSourceRowValue(Int32 listSourceRowIndex, String fieldName)
   at DevExpress.Web.Data.WebDataProxy.GetKeyValueCore(Int32 index, GetKeyValueCallback getKeyValue)
   at DevExpress.Web.Data.WebDataSelectionBase.GetSelectedValues(String[] fieldNames, Int32 visibleStartIndex, Int32 visibleRowCountOnPage)
   at DevExpress.Web.Data.WebDataProxy.GetSelectedValues(String[] fieldNames)
   at DevExpress.Web.ASPxGridView.ASPxGridView.FBSelectFieldValues(String[] args)
   at DevExpress.Web.ASPxGridView.ASPxGridView.GetCallbackResultCore()
   at DevExpress.Web.ASPxGridView.ASPxGridView.GetCallbackResult()
   at DevExpress.Web.ASPxClasses.ASPxWebControl.System.Web.UI.ICallbackEventHandler.GetCallbackResult()
```

Am I doing something wrong?

Any help will be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

suggest you avoid ObjectDataSource and do your binding in the code-behind.

You can generate your client-side code using the ObjectDataSource, and then remove it.

IMHO, ObjectDataSource and friends are not professional grade.